# Final demand for CES nested in Cobb-Douglas production function

Tags: cobb-douglas, endogenous-growth, ces

I am deriving the final demand for intermediate good $x_j$ for the following final producer's problem:
\begin{equation}
    \max_{{ k_{t}, x_{j,t}}} K^{1-\alpha}X^\alpha - R_tK_t - \int_{0}^{N_t}p_{j,t}x_{j,t}dj
\end{equation}

with $Y_t$ as numeraire and $z_{j,t}$ is an exogenous shock.

\begin{equation}
    X_t = \left[\int_{0}^{N_t} z_{j,t}^{1-\alpha} x_{j,t}^{\frac{\vartheta-1}{\vartheta}} dj \right]^{\frac{ \vartheta}{\vartheta-1}}
\end{equation}

I obtain the following demand. However, I am not sure on whether k_{t} is supposed to appear in its demand:
\begin{equation}
    x_{j,t}= k_t z_{j,t} (\frac{\alpha}{P_{j,t}})^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{equation}